# How to find items by date when the field is datetime?

Tags: cakephp

I have a model with a DateTime field.
How can I get all entries by Date even if the column is DateTime?

Example table Cars:

```
id; expiration
1;2014-12-22 00:00:00
2;2014-12-22 03:12:00
3;2014-10-09 01:10:29
```

If I do this:

```
$this->Car->find("all", array('conditions' => array('expiration' => '2014-12-22' ) ))
```

I get only the item with ID 1 (2014-12-22 00:00:00)

But I need all the items (1 and 2)
Any ideas how to accomplish this? in MySql I could do something like this:

```
SELECT * ... FROM..WHERE DATE_FORMAT(conditions, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2014-12-22'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->Car->find("all", array('conditions' => array('DATE(ondate)' => '2014-12-22') ));
```

This will generate

```
SELECT * ... FROM..WHERE WHERE DATE(ondate) = '2014-12-22'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your query as shown below:

```
$this->Car->find("all", array(
                           'conditions' => array(
                              'DATE(expiration)' => '2014-12-22'
                           ) 
                       )
               );
```

In the above query, Mysql now compare only date not the date and time as it was using in the query mentioned by you.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to search trough a range: 00:00:00 - 23:59:59
http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am not using mongodb. Only cakephp, php, mysql and  js.